# creating new thread using Qthread-Qt5

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt5, qthread

I am trying to create a new thread `gpsthread` which should run in the back ground, and store the value.

```
class gpsthread: public QThread{
    Q_OBJECT
private:nrega_status_t status2;

public: 
explicit gpsthread(QObject *parent = 0):QThread(parent) {
    // QTimer *t = new QTimer(this);
    // connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processgps()));
    // t->start(10000);
 }
 void run(){
    qDebug()<<"inside gps thread\n";
    QTimer *t = new QTimer(this);
     connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processgps()));
     t->start(10000);
    }

public slots:void processgps(){
    int status2;
    status2=gps_management();
}
};
```

My main class is quickview.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

QString file = "qml/main.qml";
QApplication app(argc, argv);
TranslationTest myObj;
QuickView view;
subthread object;
gpsthread obj;
gprsthread gprs;
view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("rootItem", (QObject *)&myObj);

    obj.start();
//from subthread
QObject::connect(&object, SIGNAL(batterytoqml(QVariant,QVariant)),item, SLOT(frombattery(QVariant,QVariant)));
QObject::connect(&gprs, SIGNAL(gprstoqml(QVariant)),item, SLOT(fromgprs(QVariant)));
return app.exec();
```

}

I have tried this as well

```
class gpsthread: public QThread{
    Q_OBJECT
private:nrega_status_t status2;

public:QTimer* t; 
explicit gpsthread(QObject *parent = 0):QThread(parent) {
    // QTimer *t = new QTimer(this);
    // connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processgps()));
    // t->start(10000);
 }
 void run(){
    qDebug()<<"inside gps thread\n";
    t = new QTimer(this);
     connect(t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processgps()));
     t->start(10000);
exec();    
}

public slots:void processgps(){
    int status2;
    status2=gps_management();
}
};
```

But it is giving error saying

```
 QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread
```

If I create object in constructor then also it will give the same error because the object will be created in the main thread.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inheriting from QThread is not the recommended usage. QThread is a complete class that runs an event loop, which is generally what you need. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html) recommends using a worker object that inherits from QObject and does work in a slot. The worker is moved into a QThread. When a connected signal is sent, the slot will run in the correct thread.

```
class gpsworker: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit gpsworker(QObject *parent = 0):
    QObject(parent)
    {}

public slots:
    void processgps() {
        qDebug() << "processgps()" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
}

void OwnerClass::startWorker() {
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    QThread *thread = new QThread(this);
    this->worker = new gpsworker();
    this->worker->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this->worker, SLOT(processgps()) );
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this->worker, SLOT(deleteLater()) );
    thread->start();
    timer->start();
}
```

If you want the timer to live in the other thread as well, `QTimer::start` is a slot.

Comment: thanks explaining this...This is indeed the correct way to use Threads.

Comment: Aren't you missing `timer->setSingleShot(true);` there?

Comment: @Jack single shot was not in the question, and so I did not add it in my answer. Given the lengthy timeout one might reasonably suppose the worker is expected to `processgps` on that regular interval.

Answer (score 1):

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thready
```

is beacuse `t = new QTimer(this)` in the `run()` is creating an object in the child thread but `this` which point at `gpsthread` is in the main thread. A simple solution is `t = new QTimer()` without a parent and delete the timer in the destructor. Here is an example:

```
class gpsthread : public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit gpsthread(QObject *parent = 0):
        QThread(parent)
        ,timer(NULL) {
        qDebug() << "Parent thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
    ~gpsthread() {
        quit();
        wait();
        delete timer;
    }
protected:
    void run() {
        qDebug() << "Inside gps thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
        timer = new QTimer;  // no parent
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(processgps()));
        timer->start(1000);
        exec();
    }

public slots:
    void processgps() {
        qDebug() << "processgps()" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }

private:
    QTimer *timer;
};
```

---

Soon you will find out console print:

```
Parent thread 0x3b28
inside gps thread 0x3f10
processgps() 0x3b28
processgps() 0x3b28
processgps() 0x3b28
processgps() 0x3b28
```

which means `processgps()` is not working in your child thread. This is because this slot is a member of `gpsthread` which is in the main thread. A simple solution is call `processgps()` directly and use `sleep()` as timer:

```
class gpsthread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit gpsthread(QObject *parent = 0):
        QThread(parent)
        , abort(false) {
        qDebug() << "Parent thread" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
    ~gpsthread() {
        abort = true;
        wait();
    }
protected:
    void run() {
        while(!abort) {
            sleep(1);
            processgps();
        }
    }
public slots:
    void processgps() {
        qDebug() << "processgps()" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
private:
    bool abort;
};
```

This is not a nice solution, a recommanded way is creating a worker to do all the job and  then use [QObject::moveToThread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) as said in [QThread Document](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qthread.html#details)